# Correct way to show Login Screen followed by UITabbarController menu

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I need to implement the following and I wanted to know the correct way to do it.

when the iPhone application launches, I need to show a logo image for 2 seconds followed by showing a login screen that allows the person to login or create an account. Once the person logs in, i need to show a tabbarcontroller menu options.

This is how I'm currently doing it:

In the `AppDelegate`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    LoginViewController *viewController0 = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *aNavigationController0 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController0];    
    self.window.rootViewController = aNavigationController0;    
    // I also implement an iVar of the UITabBarController here...
    // ....
}
```

The `@implementation`:

```
@implementation LoginViewController

- (IBAction)createNewAccountButtonClicked:(id)sender {      
    AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    delegate.window.rootViewController = delegate.tabBarController;
}
```

So, my questions are:

1. Is this the correct way to show the tabbar for my purpose?
2. In this scheme of things, I cannot show the logo animated. Any pointers on how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The code below assumes you're using ARC, if you're not then you'll need to do your MRC.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window                             = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    self.tabBarController                   = [[UITabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController          = self.tabBarController;

    LoginViewController *loginViewController= [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    loginViewController.delegate            = self;
    UINavigationController *loginNavCont    = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginViewController];

    [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:loginNavCont animated:NO];

    UIImageView *splashScreen = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default"]];
    [self.window addSubview:splashScreen];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:2.0
                        options:0
                     animations:^{
                         splashScreen.alpha = 0.0;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [splashScreen removeFromSuperview];
                     }];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (void)loginViewControllerShouldBeDismissed:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    [self.tabBarController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I tried it . The splash animation worked,                                                            but the login gave two issues : firstly, a compiler error saying that the delegate property not found on UIViewController,  so i commented out the delegate line. Second issue was that it did not show the loginnavcon in modal view. Pls suggest how can I correct

Comment: i was able to get it done by doing the following but now the issue is that the modal loginview is coming up but hidingthe tabbar.. I need to keep showing the tab bar:                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         
                         [splashScreen removeFromSuperview];
                         [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:aNavigationController0 animated:YES];

                     }];

Comment: That seems like a strange view hierarchy, as such I can only provide limited suggestions. You could have another UITabBarController and present that modally with the login view controller, or you could have the login view controller as a tab bar item of your rootViewControoller